# Laravel 6 How to get a count from a column

Tags: foreach, count

I am trying to build a dynamic accordion, which generates cards for each RsClass, and assigns to each one of the cards the Applicants in the RsClass.

```
<div class="accordion" id="rsClasses">
                @foreach ($rsClasses as $rsClass)
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header card-header-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ $rsClass->name }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="{{ $rsClass->name }}">
                        <h4 class="card-title">{{ $rsClass->name }}</h4>

                        <p class="card-category"> Nº de Candidatos:{{ $counter }} </p>

                    </div>
                    <div id="{{ $rsClass->name }}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#rsClasses">
                        <div class="card-body table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-hover">
                                <thead class="text-info">
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Categorização</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach ($applicants as $applicant)
                                    @if($rsClass->id == $applicant->rs_class_id)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                                    <input class="form-check-input applicantsSelect" type="checkbox" value="{{$applicant->id}}">
                                                    <span class="form-check-sign">
                                                        <span class="check"></span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            {{ $applicant->id }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            {{ $applicant->name }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            {{ $applicant->category }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="d-flex">
                                            <form action="/applicants/{{ $applicant->id }}" method="post">
                                                @csrf
                                                @method('put')
                                                <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Edit Task" class="btn btn-info btn-link btn-sm">
                                                    <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                                                </button>
                                            </form>
                                            <form action="/applicants/{{ $applicant->id }}" method="post">
                                                @csrf
                                                @method('delete')
                                                <button type="submit" rel="tooltip" title="Remove" class="btn btn-info btn-link btn-sm" value="DELETE">
                                                    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                                                </button>
                                            </form>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
```

This is my accordeon, and it works. The only thing I'm struggling with is to present the number of applicants in each RsClass.
At the moment, I have in my Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $applicants = Applicant::all();
    $rsClasses = RsClass::all();
    $rsClasses = RsClass::simplePaginate(10);
    $counter = \DB::table('rs_classes')
            ->join('applicants', 'rs_classes.id', '=', 'applicants.rs_class_id')
            ->count('applicants.id');

    return view('applicants.index')
    ->with(compact('applicants', 'rsClasses', 'counter'));
}
```

and what I get is:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwhMH.png)

How do I get the count for each RsClass?

Thanks in advance!